# LaTeX で画像が読み込まれない

Tags: latex

TeXShopでLaTeX文書を作成しています。

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{diceVM10.png}

\end{document}
```

というコードで同じフォルダ内の画像を読み込もうとしたところ、`This file needs format pLaTeX2e but this is LaTex2e`とのエラーコードが出たため、TeXの設定を「LaTeX, TeX+DVI」と直し再度試したところ、今度は

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (pdf:image) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (bbox) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (0) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (0) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (720) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (432) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (0) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (width) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword (142.26378pt) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: Unknown keyword ((diceVM10.png)) in \special will be ignored
/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips: No \special psfile was given; figure will be blank
] 
### ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5  /tmp/altpdflatex.1750-1703865669/figurescode.ps /tmp/altpdflatex.1750-1703865669/figurescode.pdf
Error: /undefined in llx
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:766/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:102/200(L)--   --dict:103/300(L)--   --dict:34/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 31773
GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.1750-1703865669/figurescode.pdf ()
```

というコンソール出力と共に白紙がコンパイルされてきました。うまく画像が読み込まれるようにするための改善、および設定について詳しく説明していただけませんか？

Comment: graphicxの読み込み時にdvipdfmxオプションを指定していますが、ログを見る限り実際にはdvipsが使用されているようです。まず使用するDVIウェアの設定が意図通りになっていないと思われます。

Comment: また、書き込んでいただいたLaTeXソースでは`This file needs format pLaTeX2e but this is LaTex2e`というエラーが出るはずはないと思います。日本語用のLaTeXを使ってくださいという趣旨のエラーですが、そのソースはarticleクラスを使用した欧文用のもので、日本語用文書の要素が1つも見当たりません。実際には、ここに記載したのとは別のコードを処理しようとしたのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿主です。This file needs format pLaTeX2e but this is LaTex2eのエラーに関してはコンパイル当初は発生しており、同種の質問への回答を観てDVIに変更後は解決しました。但し、コンパイルエラーが起きていない分却って原因箇所の究明が困難になっています。是非とも皆様のお力をお借りしたいです。

Comment: とりあえずgraphicxの読み込みを`\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`にするとどうなりますか？ また、書こうとされている文書（卒論）は日本語の文書ですか、それとも英語の文書ですか？ 英語であればdvipsを使用しても文書を作成できますが、日本語の場合はdvipdfmxを使用する必要があるので、上記がうまくいっても別の対応が必要です。

Comment: 投稿主です。問題が解決しました。Texshopにてメイン設定を変更した結果正しく実行されました。同様にして参考文献も掲載できています。皆様お騒がせ致しました。